# What is the simplest batch scheduler to set up on a small linux cluster?

Tags: linux, administration, cluster

We have about 10 heterogeneous machines we would like to run various jobs on. The current situation is that people log in on a machine with ssh, see if other people are running stuff on it, then use screen to run the job.

I'd like to automate this process, but I don't have enough time to install a full-fledged cluster solution. So what's the simplest thing I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [GNU Queue](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-queue/)? it's fairly easy to set up.

Comment: Quote: "At this moment there are no versions available for download". 
And "Development Status: 2 - Pre-Alpha".

Comment: Also, the website appears to be dead. It did seem like a good candidate, though.

Comment: @Harry, if you actually read the website it says *A completely new code base is under development*. Previous versions are still available: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-queue/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run same jobs in parallel on many machines, check [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Automating_ssh_and_scp_across_multiple_hosts) excellent article (not really Debian-specific). You can then set up a cronjob on some 'master' machine that would perform it on others or just do it manually.

Comment: That's nice, but at least some load balancing and queue management would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a few users and you want a quick solution, what about a centralized schedule/calendar? Just have people schedule time as they would a lab/conference room. it would take all of 25 min to setup and guaranties resources as long as everyone plays nice.

Comment: That's basically what we're doing at the moment :) I want something a bit more automated, so we don't have to talk about it and can concentrate on more important stuff.

Comment: I have not used it, but the guy sitting across from me said to look into torque.
http://www.clusterresources.com/products/torque-resource-manager.php

Answer (score 0):

I thing that [SGE](http://gridengine.sunsource.net/) is pretty easy and straight forward. I even run it on all my machines at home.